# What happens to my itunes url if I change my app's name?

Tags: ios

On the whole internet I didn't find any kind of answer for this question.

What happens to my itunes url if I change my app's name ? I mean my app url contains my apps name so if I change the name then chracters in url also changes and my old app url dies out but maybe changing name with a patch has no effect on app url. I dont know which one will happen.

I am asking because I am going to add my app's advertisement into another app and that apps name is going to be different so if I make a mistake my advertisement will be worthless.

Here is an example(I put xxxx instead of my app name and 11111111 instead of my i.)

https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/xxxxxxxx/id1111111111?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2

This is my app's url its name is I am going to use these url for ads.

So if I change my name to yyyyyyyyyy does the url stay same or adress changes ?

Will it turn the url below or stay same ?

https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/yyyyyyyyy/id1111111111?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, if you don't include the app name part, the link works all the same, e.g.:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id548271470?mt=8
```

It seems that what really matters is the app ID and that is not going to change if you just change the app name.